# Constraints for buttons between all device sizes xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I have three buttons laid out like this in Xcode:
http://s5.postimg.org/45xczyc3r/Screen_Shot_2015_08_04_at_12_34_41_AM.png

As you can see, I have errors for my constraints within my storyboard. I used constraints from a picture that someone from here on stack overflow drew up for me:

http://s5.postimg.org/6303rxjgn/constraints.png

I've tried many other constraints but I can't seem to figure out what constraints to use.

How can I fix this so it looks like it does in the storyboard across all iPhones and iPads? Landscape mode will not be a part of this application.

Comment: Here is what it looks like in a 4s simulator with those constraints that were drawn up for me: http://s5.postimg.org/taodddbk7/Screen_Shot_2015_08_04_at_12_35_11_AM.png

Comment: It looks like you need to add a fixed space between the two top buttons to keep them wide. You might also want to add a minimum height to each of the buttons as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I add constraint for 3 button as per your need I hope that will help:

Button 1:

[image]

Button 2:

[image]

Button 3:

[image]

[HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=79365499037428339276) is the sample project for more Info.

Comment: Can you do this but with the buttons having a height of 48? If you could do that and show me that would be great? @DharmeshKheni

Comment: Here is your updated project with button height 48: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05345747780335051719

Answer (score 0):

This Constraints Work for me.

Bottom Button

Pin->Leading,Trailing,Bottom,Height consttraints.

Select Both Button

Pin->Equal Width (Equal Height if required)

Left Button
Align->Leading Edges

Right Button
Aligh->Trailing Edges